# What should be the correct MySQL queries for this?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
id name priority urgency output
1  mark 0        0       A
2  mark 0        1       B
3  mark 0        0       C
4  erik 0        0       D
5  erik 0        0       E
```

I want to increase the priority of the entry with the highest urgency for each name in the list, or the oldest one in the list if there are equal urgencies. And after this I want the entry with the highest priority for each name in the list. So after the first run the table should look like this:

```
id name priority urgency output
1  mark 0        0       A
2  mark 1        1       B
3  mark 0        0       C
4  erik 1        0       D
5  erik 0        0       E
```

what I then want from the database is the link with the highest priority for each name, so this:

```
id name priority urgency output
2  mark 1        1       B
4  erik 1        0       D
```

Is there someone out there that knows how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

Update query:

```
Update user_priority u1, 
(
select min(id) as id
from user_priority inner join
(select name,max(urgency)as max_urg
from user_priority 
group by name) as user_urgency on (user_priority.name = user_urgency.name 
and user_priority.urgency = user_urgency.max_urg)
group by user_priority.name) u2

set priority =priority +1

where u1.id = u2.id
```

Get highest priority record for each name:

```
select *
from user_priority

where id in (
select min(id)
from user_priority inner join

(select name,max(urgency)as max_urg
from user_priority 
group by name) as user_urgency on (user_priority.name = user_urgency.name 
and user_priority.urgency = user_urgency.max_urg)
group by user_priority.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd use this query to select all unique names in the database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM mytable ORDER BY name;
```

From there you can get the first urgent one, or if that doesn't apply, the first non-urgent one:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    name = '%'
ORDER BY
    urgency DESC, output ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Then update that line with a new priority:

```
UPDATE mytable SET priority = 1 WHERE id = %
```

Obviously the `SELECT` to get the prioritised items is then trivial.

Comment: downside of this is that every name would get it's own query. In my example there's two names, but in the actual database there are 3227 names at the moment...

Comment: That constraint wasn't mentioned in your question. In practice, is the performance of those queries critical? Are you doing this in a web request, or offline? If you were to do it in a cron, then its taking 10s of seconds (rather than a second or so) may be fine for your use case.

Comment: (Btw, 3227 records is not many. Try it my way and see how long it takes - those queries are trivial, even for a very lowly server).

Comment: Indeed, that's true. But this is a function that is going to be called regularly. So speed is important. I have been looking around on StackOverflow some more and found that this is a common problem. Basically "order first, then group" brings up the most hints. This most likely can be solved with some kind of join, but I never got the hang of those...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - not wrong exactly, but perhaps not specific enough. "I'd use PHP to run these queries" would have been better - the OP has specified this as a PHP problem.

Comment: ayou're right @halfer. I couldn't think of the right word to describe my edit at the time. Sorry :)

Comment: @patrick - notwithstanding, do it the easy way first, then refactor if you need to. Imo there's nothing worse in development than not having working code, and it'll take you ten minutes to get it working my way. If you would clarify whether you are calling this inside a web request, that might be useful to other readers.

Comment: It doesn't make sense running 3227 queries from PHP. That's just too slow and too much of a load for the server. The query is run too often for that. I'm looking at this now: select * from ( select * from table order by urgency desc ) urgency_table group by name, this returns the correct table, but is very, very slow. The entire table is MUCH bigger than the 3227 names that are in it (at the moment over 45K entries)

Comment: Excellent. Just guessing: did you add an index on your sort columns? `:-D`